# Updating mysql bit datatype using codeigniter active record

Tags: php, activerecord, codeigniter

I have a table with one columns datatype as BIT(1) . I am using active record of codeigniter for performing queries. But the setting of bit is not working. Does anybody has idea about how to do it? Or I have to get back to normal query?

Following is the code snippet:

```
function itemUpdate($options=array()) {
if(isset($options['isAvailable']))
   $itemDB->set('isAvailable',$options['isAvailable']);
   $itemDB->where('id', $options['id']);
   $itemDB->update('Item');
}
```

Comment: What's the active record code you're using?

Comment: What value is in `$options['isAvailable']`?

Comment: $options['isActive'] can be either 0 or 1

Comment: isActive or isAvailable? $itemDB->set('isAvailable', (int) $options['isAvailable']);

Comment: @Phil sorry my mistake, its $options['isAvailable']. Thanks for solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often use:

```
$this->db->set('foo', (int) !empty($options['foo']));
```

Makes a 0/1 response pretty foolproof.

Comment: $options['foo'] gives 1 in either case how can you cast it to int??

Comment: I think it would be enough just to set the (int), no need for the !empty(n),  because MySQL doesn't like the single quotes wrapped around the BIT type value. I had this problem, just used the (int) to declare my value as an integer, and voila!

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this using cakephp 1.3.10 framework (php 5.2.9 | mysql 5.1.33)

```
$decimal_value = hexdec(bin2hex($bin_value));
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: This is more generic and can be used for BIT with lengths more than 1.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered this about Codeigniter, that the Active Record query builder automatically adds single quotes around the value, and that the MySQL BIT type won't accept the single quotes around a value.

To see what the actual generated query is, add this line immediately following your query: `echo $this->db->queries[0];`

You can also `var_dump( $this->db );`

Now you will see the problem with the query, but it's a problem that I think exists only because you're trying to set a BIT data type.

So, where this works:

```
// Given that $options['isAvailable'] = 12 and $options['id'] = 2
UPDATE Item SET `isAvailable` = 12 WHERE id=2
```

This fails:

```
UPDATE Item SET `isAvailable` = '12' WHERE id=2
```

...and it only fails because your column isAvailable is of type BIT.

Above, @phil-sturgeon gave us the answer, but we can just simplify it like so:

```
$itemDB->set('isAvailable', (int) $options['isAvailable']);
$itemDB->where('id', $options['id']);
$itemDB->update('Item');
```